# Linq Query for EAV design table

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-attribute-value

I had a situation to use EAV design tables and I am new to this design,I am struck with a select query. Below is my query structure and data.

```
TABLE1:
 Id KeyName
 1  Name
 2  Age

TABLE2:
ID  TABLE1_ID VALUE
 1    1        ABC
 2    2        12
 3    1        CDF
 4    2        14    
 5    1        XYZ
 6    2        13
 7    1        CSF
 8    2        10 

EXPECTED OUTPUT: Get all the values which are greater than 12 AND Value contains "C".
i.e., 
  Table2_ID  Result  Table1_KeyName
       1      ABC      Name
       2      12       Age
       3      CDF      Name
       4      14       Age
```

Options I tried are:

```
        Var temp = (from c in Table2
                    where c.Value > 12 && c.Table1.KeyName.Contains("C")
                    Select new
                   {
                    ID = c.ID,
                    Result = C.Value
                   });
```

the above query didn't returned any result, as filters(in where clause) are across rows. I even tried "OR" condition in where clause, it returns me everything. Please do help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong, did you type it in here or copy and paste it from your work?

Do you have this table setup in an ORM such as Entity Framework? So that there is a relationship setup between table1 and table2, so you don't have to 'join' them?

To be more 'correct' it should be...

```
    Var temp = (from c in Table2
                where c.Value > 12 && c.Table1.Name.Contains("C")
                Select new
               {
                ID = c.ID,
                Name = c.Table1.Name,
                Value = c.Value
               });
```

Or if the relationship isn't in an ORM your using explicitly specify the join as follows:

```
    Var temp = (from c in Table2
                join c1 in Table1 on c.Table1_ID equals c1.Id
                where c.Value > 12 && c.Table1.Name.Contains("C")
                Select new
               {
                ID = c.ID,
                Name = c.Table1.Name,
                Value = c.Value
               });
```

Edit: then it should be an OR, not AND

```
    Var temp = (from c in Table2
                where c.Value > 12 || c.Value.Contains("C")
                Select new
               {
                ID = c.ID,
                Result = c.Value,
                KeyName = c.Table1.Name
               });
```

Comment: Yes it is in Entityframework and has a relation between table 1 and table 2. I updated the question please check it.

Comment: Where keyname contains C or should it be where value contains C ? It seems that you need to rethink what your problem actually is.